# I am getting this error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, syntax-error, ddl

```
create table passenger(pnr number(10) primary key,
trainnumber number(5) foreign key references train(trainnumber),
noofseats number(4),
price number(4),
doj varchar2(10))
```

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

The `foreign key` expression is redundant (read: wrong). The syntax is just to add `references`:

```
create table passenger(pnr number(10) primary key,
trainnumber number(5) references train(trainnumber), -- here
noofseats number(4),
price number(4),
doj varchar2(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

change yout `CREATE TABLE` statement to be like below

```
create table passenger(pnr number(10) primary key,
trainnumber number(5), 
noofseats number(4),
price number(4),
doj varchar2(10),
foreign key (trainnumber) references train(trainnumber))
```